# vba excel write sub which is accessible for both modules but invisible to the user

Tags: excel, access-modifiers, vba

I want to move some of my util subs into a different module. The problem is that if I do it I must set their access modifier to be "public" and then they are visible to the user when he presses the "macros" button.

What should I do?
How can I use the Utils module without making its subs visible to the users?

Thanks, 
Li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the subs as `Private` so that they are not visible to the users. And then if you want to call them, use `Application.Run`

For example

**Module 1**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample1()
    Application.Run "Module2.Sample2"
End Sub
```

**Module2**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Sample2()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks :) and if my macro receives an argument it's: 

Application.Run "Module2.Sample2", arg?

Comment: `Application.Run "Module2.Sample2",arg1,agr2,arg3...`

Answer (score 0):

Save your utils modules as an excel Addin, instead of a workbook. Make sure the file name ends in .xla or .xlam. This way only other vba code in excel addins and workbooks can see them and they will be invisible to the user.

Alternatively, if there is just one Sub you want to hide or saving as an .xla is not an option. You could give your Sub an optional parameter

```
Option Explicit

public Sub Sample1(Optional x as string = "")
    ' Code goes here, just as before.
End Sub
```

then it won't show in the run macro dialog, even if it's public.